# style d3 axis with js rather than CSS

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

Is there a way to style a d3.js chart axis with js similar to this:

```
 svg.append("text")
     .attr("x",xPos)
     .attr("y",yPos -3)
     .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
     .attr("font-size", "10px")
     .attr("font-weight", "bold")
     .attr("fill", "black")
     .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
     .attr("id", "tooltip")
     .attr("transform", "translate(" + width/2 + ")")
     .text(d.name +": "+ d.value);
```

rather than using the standard method of using CSS. Here's an example CSS that I want to remove and style my axis with JS

```
.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd always advocate styling using CSS if you can - it's what it's designed for, but yes you can also style things manually if you wish.

For example if you want to style the axis line, you would take your "container" or element in which you added the axis to (I'll assume an `svg:g` in this case) and do something like the following:

```
g.selectAll(".axis line")
 .style("fill", "none")
 .style("stroke", "#000")
 .style("shape-rendering", "crispEdges");
}
```